# What are the additional expenses in jdbc in addition to the time taken by the db to run the query?

Tags: database, jdbc

I wanted to know what are the additional expenses in running a query using jdbc in addition to the actual time taken by the database to run the query and how expensive are they.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Some time will be used, to create Object (Strings, etc.) ~some nano seconds
- Network-Overhead. ~10-50 mili seconds

At startup (before the first query), there will be some time, loading the jdbc driver and creating the connection.

Comment: How about converting the sql relation output to ResultSet object?

Comment: That, what I meant with creating objects. The question is to broad, to be more precise. The most databases drivers just open a pointer to the result and create only the objects needed for the actual row (or some more as a batch).

Comment: Thanks. That was my major concern. If the relation would need to be copied over or if ResultSet is just a pointer.